# How to write better way to python inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have written this,

```
class Sp():
  def __init__(self):
    self.price = 1
class A(Sp):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    self.test = True
class B(A):
  pass
class C(A):
  pass
class D(A):
  """In this class I don't want to inherit Sp class, but need A class"""
  def __init__(self):
     super(D, self).__init__()
     self.me = 'ok'
     self.list_ = [Sp()]
```

**Sp** is the Parent class for **A**. And I'm using **A** class in **B**,**C** and **D**, But **D** don't need Sp inheritance instead it needs **Sp** instance object inside **D**(Please look into **D** class). I want to stop **Sp** inheritance in **D**, is there any good way to write this ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to inherit `A`?

Comment: Yes it has lot of stuff which has already implemented, But I don't need some class attributes of A, that's why I wrote Sp class.

Comment: @dhana Why not using composition instead using inheritance in D then?

Comment: @BPL, Yes I can use composition, but it needs lot of code change. So using inheritance less code change and less error prone.

Comment: whoever giving down vote, please give reason for that so I can update my question if needed.

Comment: @dhana may you change the architecture:
`class A():`, `class Sp():`, `class ASp(A, Sp):`, `class B(ASp):`, `class D(A):`

Comment: I haven't downvoted. But... It seems like your inheritance is badly designed. I'd suggest refactor and redesign the whole thing instead patching around to "make it work"

Comment: I agreed with @SergeyBelash, Thanks BPL for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit from `A` without inheriting from `Sp` if `A` itself inherits from `Sp`. You could try to work around it though, by making `A` inherit from two classes, one of which implements the non-`Sp` behaviors (say, call it `Abits`), and `Sp` (`class A(Abits, Sp):`). Then have `B` and `C` inherit `A`, while `D` inherits solely from `Abits`.

If `A` doesn't need to be created independently, you could just make `A` not inherit from `Sp` at all, and have `B` and `C` inherit from both `A` and `Sp` (`class B(A, Sp):`), while `D` only inherits from `A`, which saves the need for a separate `Abits`.

Lastly, you might consider composition. Have `D` not inherit from anything, just contain an instance of `A`. Then use [the `__getattr__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to get attributes from `A` when they're not defined on `D`:

```
class D(object):  # Explicitly inheriting from object not needed on Py3
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.a = A(...)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Only called when attribute "name" doesn't exist on instance of D
        return getattr(self.a, name)
```

You might also need to use `__setattr__` if you need to mutate the `A` instance. This is trickier (because `__setattr__` is called unconditionally, not just when an attribute doesn't exist), but there are plenty of examples of using it available if you search.

Comment: Wow, that sounds complex. Why not redesign properly (even if it needs lot of code change) instead patching around?

Comment: @BPL: None of this is "patching around" (`Abits` is a bit hacky if `A` and `Abits` are not distinguishable for anything but inheritance purposes, but if you can just decouple `A` and `Sp`, or if the non-`Sp` parts of `A` really have a useful separation, it's pretty simple and intuitive). Besides, I don't have enough information to give higher level design suggestions. Composition is the only real option if the OP's scenario doesn't allow them to change the definitions of `A`/`B`/`C` (they might come from an external package for all I know).

Comment: Fair enough, maybe the term "patching around" wasn't appropiate. In any case, I'd say I do agree with the opinion exposed by this [article than rewriting from scratch is a bad idea](http://www.humus.name/index.php?ID=351). I think for the problem given refactoring the bad relationships between the set of classes will be a proper solution in the long term